# Work-around for the absence of "save-as" in OS X 10.7

Tags: macos

Is there a more convenient work-around for Apple's decision to drop the "save as" command than clicking on duplicate, then save the copy which then displays the file structure?

I have tried the app "Default Folders" and it does not solve the problem (at least in my hands).

Comment: I found this article very useful, not only for work-arounds but also as a general commentary on Apple's new document model: http://tidbits.com/article/13187

Comment: And that article indeed contains a workaround, which still works in High Sierra:  "You can return the Save As… command to the File menu with it's traditional key command by adding it as a Keyboard Shortcut:
1. Open System Preferences from the Apple menu and go to Keyboard/Keyboard Shortcuts 
2. Choose Application Shortcuts from the list on the left 
3. Click the plus button [+] at the bottom to add a new shortcut 
3. Type Save As… with the ellipsis for the Menu Title 
4. Use the traditional Command+Shift+S (or anything to your liking) for the Keyboard Shortcut 
5. Finally, click Add"

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid not. You could, though, add a shortcut to the *Duplicate* command, to make it more like the *Save as*. To do so just:

1. Go to **System Preferences / Keyboard / Keyboard Shortcuts**.
2. Select *Application Shortcuts* and click the add button.
3. Set it to **All Applications** and enter `Duplicate` as *Menu Title*. It's case sensitive, so make sure it's written with a capital D.
4. Choose a keyboard shortcut and hit *Add*.

**Mountain Lion**, by the way, has the *Save As* command back. Holding down <kbd>Option</kbd> while clicking the *File* menu, will turn the *Duplicate* command into *Save as...*.

Answer (score 0):

Sometime between when this question was asked and macOS 13, the shortcut was restored.

To replicate Save As...:

1. Press <kbd>⌘ + ⇧ + S</kbd> or File > Duplicate
2. Press <kbd>⌘ + S</kbd> or File > Save...

You will now have a file save dialog you can complete to save the copy